Is there any way to make the whole content of combobox item a different color?
I am looking for a way to change the color of the content of the entire combobox item, not just the text as in the image below:

I am trying to achieve something like this:

The code I have so far and what I was able to find on the internet:
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        Height="49" Width="84">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>


You can set it by ItemContainerStyle to like this:
    <ComboBox 
ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
    Height="49" Width="84"
        DisplayMemberPath="Name">
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ComboBox>

Do you wanna have border around every ComboBoxItem? You can set BorderBrush to Red too. Or hide it by BorderThickness to set it to "0"
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />

Hopefully this will help you.
